# Cursor delete position

Tags: android, sqlite, position, cursor

WHY?
please

select code

```
private void selectData() {

    String sql = "select ID, money, memo, date, type from " + _TABLENAME;
    mCursor = mDbOpenHelper.mDB.rawQuery(sql, null);
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mi = new MyItem(
                mCursor.getString(0),
                mCursor.getString(3),
                mCursor.getString(2),
                mCursor.getString(1),
                mCursor.getString(4));
        arItem.add(mi);
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mCursor.close();
}
```

delete button click, delete code

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    /* problem */

    final String sql = "delete from "+_TABLENAME+" where ID = "+ selectPosition;
}
});
```

Comment: `" where ID = "+ selectPosition;` => You are falling in the **common error** to think that the `position` in the Spinner or ListView corresponds to the `id` in the database table. While they are really **unrelated**. And `pleasepleaseplease` avoid all this `pleasepleaseplease` **garbage** at the end of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` is wrong, you should use the id you retervied via the cursor and not the position. You may try something like this

```
 String sql = "delete from "+_TABLENAME+" where ID = "+ mi.get(selectPosition).id;
```

here the `mi.get(selectedPosition)` returns the corresponding object you added in `selectData` method and the `.id` gets the id you passed to it via the constructor. You should use your correct variable name to achieve this